# What alternative spoke lacing patterns exist (that make a decent wheel)?

Tags: wheels, spokes, reference, wheel-building

I'd like to know of all the 'normal' ways to spoke a wheel. Currently, if you want to use a non-standard pattern, you have to run the length computations a number of times; for example, in a 3-spoke crow's foot, you'd have to compute the lengths for a radial spoking, and then again for 2x). Also, some patterns are manufacturer specific or rare and there don't exist calculators for them (G3, Paired, Twin Pair, etc.). I'd like to simplify this calculation and account for non-standard spoking patterns as well as the regular ones, however I'm not sure what patterns are out there.

To limit the question some, I'm only concerned with *proper* **lacing patterns** - a term I'll have to define:

- It has to make a working, rideable wheel. Some spokes must oppose the tension of other spokes.
- The number of leading spokes is equal to the number of trailing spokes (both 0 for radial). I realize they could just be placed randomly to make a wheel, but this isn't a *pattern*.
- *Unless there's a reason for it* (or someone's done it before), every leading spoke should be matched equally to a trailing spoke. Sure, the leading spokes could be 1x and the trailing 3x, but why do this? (If you can state a reason, then it would count)
- The spokes are all straight from a spoke hole to a rim seat, which takes any of the [twisted patterns](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_BuzxEhjqu6c/SgYm8mIwNxI/AAAAAAAABPc/rM762NAjBl4/s400/Flower+Wheels.MEDIUM.jpg) that bend spokes around other spokes (not just crossing) off the table. I suspect there are only a few ways to do this, but it's in the realm of possibility to buy ten foot spokes and go crazy, so I'm not considering them a *proper* lacing pattern.

In this context, I don't really care if it sucks, or has disadvantages x, y, and z, or get into a discussion of why bother with a certain pattern. However, any more details on them, or WHY they suck/rule I'm very interested in. I'm using this for my [wheel spoking application](http://www.wheelspoking.com) to view them and calculate lengths in a much more detailed, accurate and customizable way, which is why I'm not interested in practicality, just possibility. If you have any to add, a picture would be nice or at least a description enough for me to draw a wheel with it would be appreciated.

The obvious ones that don't need to be mentioned:

- Radial
- Crossings (1x, 2x, 3x, 4x, ...)

Comment: See [What kind of questions can I ask here?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) This Question violates at least 3 of the items on that list. Besides which, you've got the books and other resources to get this info on your own. Vote to Close.

Comment: - You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. - If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much. - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”

Comment: +1 "There isn't a complete list. The examples you've given cover a wide spectrum of possibilities, each of which can be permuted in so many different ways that making such a list would be a huge undertaking and it would have so many millions of entries that it would be useless." This is exactly what I mean. Closing the question.

Comment: This is an actual question! It is both practical, as I explained why above, and easily answerable. If anyone knows of one, add it. Thus a complete-ish list has been formed, which helps both me and anyone looking for a list like this. I've looked at many sources, and nowhere has a single unified source. Not only that, there are only a finite number of 'patterns' - I'd guess about 20 tops. There WOULD be a decently complete list, over time, if you open the question and others contribute.

Comment: There is, in addition, a complete list in theory. It just hasn't been compiled in any useful format, yet. Please describe in more detail what '3 items' I have violated. I can describe in exacting detail why it is practical to me (and others), and give you an easy example of the perfect answer: "Add these 5 (pictures of each) and those are all that I've ever seen attempted." That one answer could very well form the most complete list ever assembled on spoking patterns.

Comment: Just because I don't expect the answers to come from one single source does not make it an invalid / 'not real' question.

Comment: "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much..." pretty much covers it. I appreciate your enthusiasm, and interest in the subject of wheel building. We've all had questions which are outside the scope of this site get closed, including me. It's not personal. As for reasons, they were already given to you. Feel free to edit the question to be more specific. If you get it within the scope of the site, I'll reopen it.

Comment: In addition, your comments which consistently request answers "in detail" from users that disagree with you, are in my opinion, designed to instigate arguments or debate. Please refer to your Meta question on that subject for the site policy regarding soliciting debate.

Comment: I cannot imagine an entire book that answers this. I imagine 5-10 answers from the community to do so just fine. The 'reasons' were ASSERTED, perhaps, but I've given reasons why I disagree and then asked for some logic as to how @Sparr concluded 'millions' is even within a realm of possibility. It isn't, and I can verify this mathematically if either of you are interested. I ask for detail because it's clearly false, and I'm not looking for debate, but I do want more than unjustified assertions. Can you list specifically the 3 items I violated, so I can better restate the question?

Comment: I already did. See my second comment above. I'll not argue with you about it. Your first two viewers down voted the post, and I closed it. Doesn't that tell you that you might be wrong here? As for whether there is an entire book on the subject, I believe you own it. I recommended it to you, it's called "The Bicycle Wheel" by Jobst Brandt, and it's where you got your original photos.

Comment: Will you discuss further on the meta question I asked? I responded here 1) why it is practical and how to answer it, 2) I cannot see a book on the subject of just a list of lacing patterns (I'm not asking about wheel building as a whole), 3) my answer has only been *partially* provided with the question, 4) I'm not interested in opinions of people's subjective use habits, and 5) there are verifiably NOT 'millions of entries'. I'm not asking for an argument, but constructive comments on how to ask this correctly.

Comment: Crow's foot and 3-lead, 3-trail are the ones I've seen used that aren't in the "obvious" list.
http://www.rouesartisanales.com/article-2443239.html
http://roadcyclinguk.com/how-to/maintenance/winter-wheel-build-part-five-lacing-patterns.html
http://sheldonbrown.com/mismatch/

Comment: As for "why use twice as many leading spokes?": http://sheldonbrown.com/power-wheel.html :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a complete list. The examples you've given cover a wide spectrum of possibilities, each of which can be permuted in so many different ways that making such a list would be a huge undertaking and it would have so many millions of entries that it would be useless.

Comment: If you mistook me to mean any way to connect spokes to rims, you would arrive at `(n/2)!/n` possibilities, or `39 million` for a 24 spoke wheel. I could then constrain this down to less than a million if I wished but this is not what I'm asking for. Patterns get repeated `4 - (n/2)` times per side, and have restrictions such that I doubt there are more than **20-25** that fit the definition above. I can support this further if you like.

Comment: No. Each pair of spokes can be crossed, or not crossed. A simple example is a wheel where spokes are in triplets, a pair crossed then a single radial spoke. For each triplet there are two possibilities (single spoke before or after the pair), so in a 36 spoke wheel there are 2^6 possible spoke patterns. That's just using the simplest radial/1x alternation. But you could also use groups of 4 spokes, allowing 4 options over 6 groups on a 24 spoke wheel. Wheels also come in 1..100-ish spoke counts, and while they're generally multiples of 4 that's not essential.